# There is a problem running the libIEC61850 library. iec61850.dll is required for resolution

Tags: c#, dll

There is a problem running the libIEC61850 library.
iec61850.dll is required for resolution. Help.

1. The library was downloaded from the link below.
   https://libiec61850.com/downloads/
2. Build from path libiec61850-1.5.0\dotnet\ was successful.
3. A problem occurred when executing the sample server code.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on06O.png)
4. Error contents:
   System.DllNotFoundException: 'DLL 'iec61850' Load Fail

--> The iec61850.dll file seems to be required.

I wonder how to solve it.

Comment: If you downloaded a library, check that it's not blocked - more recent versions of windows do this for dll files that haven't been "installed" https://www.limilabs.com/blog/unblock-dll-file#:~:text=You%20just%20have%20to%20open,slices%20them%20off%20the%20file.

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @Charleh Thank you for answer.

First of all, the iec61850.dll file does not exist in the downloaded file.

If that file is found, I will try to unblock it.